# How to determine that google play service to detect user activity work for sure if some sensor is available?

Tags: android, google-play-services, accelerometer, sensors, activity-recognition

In the Google play service request user activity document they given like, it will work only if the device has Significant motion senor.

But there are devices which does not have that senor also detects the user activity properly. 
And also there are devices which is having this sensor also not detecting the user activity.

Is there any list of sensor needs to be available to detect user activity using Google play services.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

it mainly uses the location  services to know whether a user is moving or idle like it used in google maps to know the users proper location

Comment: Is not location data. Actually I am finding the user activity[Idle, onFoot, ...].